# kmemcheck simple test case does not seem to work

Tags: debugging, memory-management, linux-kernel

I've built a kernel on x86_64 (kernel ver 3.18.22) with kmemcheck enabled. 
Relevant configs:

```
# grep KMEMCHECK /boot/config-3.18.22
CONFIG_HAVE_ARCH_KMEMCHECK=y
CONFIG_KMEMCHECK=y
CONFIG_KMEMCHECK_DISABLED_BY_DEFAULT=y
# CONFIG_KMEMCHECK_ENABLED_BY_DEFAULT is not set
# CONFIG_KMEMCHECK_ONESHOT_BY_DEFAULT is not set
CONFIG_KMEMCHECK_QUEUE_SIZE=64
CONFIG_KMEMCHECK_SHADOW_COPY_SHIFT=5
CONFIG_KMEMCHECK_PARTIAL_OK=y
# CONFIG_KMEMCHECK_BITOPS_OK is not set
#
```

Wrote a quick kernel module to test kmemcheck catching uninitialized slab memory accesses. The function in question that runs this simple test case:

```
static int slab_test(void)
{
    void *kbuf;
    kbuf = kmalloc(512, GFP_KERNEL);
    if (!kbuf) {
        pr_warn("out of memory!");
        return -ENOMEM;
    }
    pr_info("### slab_test: kbuf=%p\n", kbuf);
    print_hex_dump_bytes("### ", DUMP_PREFIX_ADDRESS, kbuf, 32);
    kfree(kbuf);
    return 0;
}
```

I enable kmemcheck, insert the module and call the above function, log the output - all via a small wrapper script below:

```
# cat tst.sh 
MOD=kmemchk_test
echo 0 > /proc/sys/kernel/kmemcheck
dmesg -C
rmmod ${MOD} 2>/dev/null
echo 1 > /proc/sys/kernel/kmemcheck
insmod ${MOD}.ko
sleep 1
echo 0 > /proc/sys/kernel/kmemcheck
dmesg > out.txt
#
```

My problem is this: kmemcheck does not seem to catch the uninitialized memory access at all! Here's the output:

```
# dmesg 
--snip--
kern  :info  : [  +0.000005] ### slab_test: kbuf=ffff88003ccc8000
kern  :debug : [  +0.000003] ### ffff88003ccc8000: 00 8c cc 3c 00 88 ff ff 75 6c 65 2f 6b 6d 65 6d  ...<....ule/kmem
kern  :debug : [  +0.000003] ### ffff88003ccc8010: 63 68 6b 5f 74 65 73 74 00 41 43 54 49 4f 4e 3d  chk_test.ACTION=
#
```

Any idea why? TIA..

Comment: I think *unintialized* in terms of kmemcheck is that one that provokes a page fault. Apparently not the case.

Comment: @Andy doesn't kmemcheck force a page fault by first "hiding" the page? My understanding is that's how it traps into the access.. So, that should happen and it should catch the uninitialized access yes?